# What does tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase actually do?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use Efficientnet for some object detection and are loading its checkpoint before providing some images. If I set `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True)` before doing predictions it results in bad predictions. With that I mean it only has 2 detections with a score above 0.5 threshold (there are about 10 people in the images). If I however have `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(False)` and doing predictions it has far more detections (about 8) and the threshold is ranging from 0.7 - 0.94.
Why is this happening based on the `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase()` call?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That one is a deprecated function in new versions actually. Some layers(BatchNorm - Dropout) behave differently in training and testing.

By `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True)` you actually leave them in training mode so they are active. You want them disabled when making a prediction.

For more check [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/860058301de30b6feedeb890f54f5475d26d82c7/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L411-L441).